# Create array which replace by the header with 1 and skip zero for each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
     a  b  c
     1  1  0
     0  0  1
     1  0  1
```

Where a, b and c are the headers

I have the data frame that is shown above, and I need result in the format below:

```
      [[a,b],
       [c],
       [a,c]]
```

As you can see, the headers with value 1 are present and the ones with value 0(zero) are skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [96]: df.astype(bool).apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)
Out[96]:
0    [a, b]
1       [c]
2    [a, c]
dtype: object
```

For array of values, use `.values`

```
In [102]: df.astype(bool).apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)
     ...: .values
Out[102]: array([['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c']], dtype=object)
```

Or, use `iterrows`

```
In [114]: [x[x].index.tolist() for i,x in df.astype(bool).iterrows()]
Out[114]: [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main_list = []
for ind in df.index:
    sublist = []
    for column in df.columns:
        if df.loc[ind, column]:
            sublist.append(column)  
    main_list.append(sublist)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c']]
```

hope it helps